# PHP - syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and have no idea why this is happening, I have looked at other online items, however I just cannot seem to see why I am getting this error.

```
<?php
include_once('assets/libs/posicloud/posicloud.php');

    $cloud=new posicloud();
    $out='';
    foreach ($cloud->list_templates() as $key=>$template)
    {
$out.='<option value=''.$key.'">'.$value["name"].';
    }
  return $out;
?>
```

Thankyou for any help!

Comment: Thanks, apologies but I am very new, I have read the error messages but did not understand them, thats why I posted here to see if someone could help me understand my issue.

Comment: There's something wrong with your quotes notation. As this is a very important aspect of PHP (or programming in general), I recommend reading some more about it first before we give you a bite-sized answer. For example: http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm

Comment: I was receiving this error and had to convert the file line separators from CF to CRLF.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you're working with strings in PHP you'll need to pay special attention to the formation, using `"` or `'`

```
$string = 'Hello, world!';
$string = "Hello, world!";
```

Both of these are valid, the following is not:

```
$string = "Hello, world';
```

You must also note that `'` inside of a literal started with `"` will not end the string, and vice versa. So when you have a string which contains `'`, it is generally best practice to use double quotation marks.

```
$string = "It's ok here";
```

Escaping the string is also an option

```
$string = 'It\'s ok here too';
```

More information on this can be found within the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Please remember to upvote/accept an answer if it worked for you. It'll guarantee future help down the line :-)

Comment: Ticked for most descriptive and helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong quoting: (and missing option closing tag xd)

```
$out.='<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value["name"].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'<option value=''.$key.'">'
```

should be

```
'<option value="'.$key.'">'
```

Comment: …or `sprintf( '<option value="%s">', $key );`

Answer (score 1):

You have a sintax error in your code:

try changing this line

```
$out.='<option value=''.$key.'">'.$value["name"].';
```

with

```
$out.='<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value["name"].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$out.='<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value["name"];
```

me funciono con esta

```
"<a  href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='cargar_datos_cliente(\"$row->DSC_EST\")' class='button micro asignar margin-none'>Editar</a>";
```